# How to validate serialized JSON string

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my Spring Rest Endpoint, I receive JSON as a string wrapped in request parameter. I m able to Deserialize the JSON string into an Object by using ObjectMapper of JSON class. But, I want to validate the Object's properties i.e. whether firstname, lastname are empty or null and whether phone number is of 10 digit number or not and other validations so on

My question is how I can achieve the validations of  an object in spring boot rest
Withouy having @Valid annotation in Controller methods

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveEmployee")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveEmployeeDetails(
            @Valid @RequestPart(value = "empData", required = true) String emplRegJSONString,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadFile, BindingResult result) {

        Status status = new Status();
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Request Body is " + emplRegJSONString);
            Long savedEmployeeRegisId = null;
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(emplRegJSONString)) {
                EmployeeRegistrationTbl employeeRegistrationTbl = new ObjectMapper().readValue(emplRegJSONString,
                        EmployeeRegistrationTbl.class);

               // VALIDATION SHOULD GO AHEAD HERE ON EmployeeRegistrationTbl object

            }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691591/objectmapper-readvalue

Comment: not helpfull. They are saying about convert json to class obj. But i need validation

Comment: Why don't you let Spring deserialize (and then validate) the request part for you, just as you would with a RequestBody (i.e. not using String as argument type, but using EmployeeRegistrationTbl directly)?

Comment: Totally agreeing with @JB Nizet, I just want to direct your attention to a small tutorial for [Bean Validation with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/).

Comment: Yes, you are right.. But, i need to get multipart file also from my upstream. To handle form data and image(multipart) i wanted to do like that. Hope u understand

Comment: Did you try a custom validator ? . eg : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: Ok, If i write custom validation, how can pass my employeeRegisTbl obj to vadlidation framework. I.e. how can perform validation then. I've been facing this issue since so long

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json-schema-validator project for spring boot on github.](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator)
Let's explain with an example. We try to reach a node within the json object, if we don't get this node, we'll fail our schema validation and catch it with exception.

```
public void validate(final ProcessingReport report,
    final  MessageBundle bundle, final FullData data)
    throws ProcessingException
{
    final String value = data.getInstance().getNode().textValue();
    try {
        UUID.fromString(value);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
        report.error(newMsg(data, bundle, "invalidUUID")
            .put("input", value));
    }
}
```

You can also get the result you want by using regex. Examples are also available. You can look the examples for [json-schema-validator examples on github](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/examples)

Comment: Any alternative pls.