# How to create Map from yaml file with Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

This is the class:

```
public class YamlMap {

    Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap<>();

    String get(String key) {
        return this.mp.get(key);
    }
}
```

and this is the props.yml:

```
mp:
  key1: ok
  key2: no
```

When I run:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
YamlMap ym2 = mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/props.yml"), YamlMap.class);
```

then I get error:
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "YamlMap" (class YamlMap)

Comment: it is above. The second code rectangle ;)

Comment: That's not ObjectMapper works. It would read `key1` and `key2` directly, then try to set `key1` and `key2` as fields in `YamlMap`. They don't exist as fields though, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ObjectMapper readValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691591/objectmapper-readvalue)

Comment: deserialization makes the code too complicated...

Comment: Just annotate with `mp` field with `@JsonProperty("mp")`

Comment: @michalk This isn't json.

Comment: @Frontear I just used Jackson to compile his example and it works. Jackson is not only for JSON - you can handle other formats like Yaml and CBOR. Jackson core annotations names can be misleading but it will work...

Comment: @JsonProperty doesnt work: `Error:(11, 1) java: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration`

Comment: @michalk is right. use `@JsonProperty` annotation on `mp`. It will work. just verified.

Comment: @wykopowiedz this error does not match the code that you have shown in the question.

Comment: a ok it works. I should put it on a field not a class... But it looks strange, cuz its not Json... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution is to add `@JsonProperty("mp")` above your field :

```
public class YamlMap {

    @JsonProperty("mp")
    Map<String, String> mp;
}
```

Jackson core annotation names might be misleading but even though this annotation has *Json* in its' name - it will work. Jackson can be configured to parse different formats like Yaml or CBOR - but still for mapping you would use core annotations which have *Json* in their names.

Another solution is to create a constructor and use `@JsonCreator` :

```
public class YamlMap {

    Map<String, String> mp;

    @JsonCreator
    public YamlMap(@JsonProperty("mp") Map<String, String> mp) {
        this.mp = mp;
    }
}
```